# calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,20); cannot change value of calendar.MINUTE;

Tags: java, calendar

```
public class workingWithCalender {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Initially : Hour: "+calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY+"  Minute: "+calendar.MINUTE);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,20);
    System.out.print("Finally : Hour: "+calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY+"  Minute: "+calendar.MINUTE);
}
```

}

This code is producing output:

```
Initially: hour: 11 minute:12   Finally hour: 11 minute:12
```

But i need `Finally: hour: 10 minute: 20`
What is the problem with the code and how to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `set` but not using `get`

try

```
System.out.print("Finally : Hour: "+calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) +
      "  Minute: "+calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

The values that you are Printing at the internal field numbers for the Class Calendar see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MINUTE

Also use the Calendar's static fields e.g. `Calendar.MINUTE`